# How to convert Bedrock texture pack to Java Edition Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to use a texture pack designed for the Bedrock Edition of *Minecraft*, on Java Edition. I looked at the texture names for a Java Edition texture pack and compared those to the names of the Bedrock Edition texture names, and they aren't the same. A lot of the texture names are flipped, such as:

- Jungle Log (Java = `jungle_log.png`) (Bedrock = `log_jungle.png`)

Most of the texture names are flipped, like the Jungle Log (and all of the other log types) and there are some `.json` files that are different and/or not there.

Trying to open the Bedrock texture pack would result in some animated blocks not being animated, other blocks play the wrong sound (or no sound) when broken, if OptiFine is in the mix, the skybox could be missing, which I am pretty sure would result in an always black sky, along with no sun and moon textures.

How do I convert a Bedrock texture pack for use on the Java Edition?

Comment: Technically this is off-topic, because it's asking for the recommendation of software. But I was unable to find a converter online, only in the other direction, and on softwarerecsSE you'll probably never get an answer. So I'll not vote to close this.

Comment: @FabianRöling Agreed. The OP is explicitly asking for software or a page explaining it, which wasn't necessary - if only a  method for conversion was looked after, there wouldn't have been an obvious problem with this.

Comment: It is possible to do it the other way round: http://mcrpconverter.epizy.com/?i=1. If website is ever taken down: https://mega.nz/file/eR5zAA4B#Fhry_6rwlMs5VkIajLnOnRMhNipXgXvsuHFMuS6e7g8.